# fscanf scans from stream to first variable

Tags: c, file, memory, readfile

I am working on a project with frames. Every frame has name, path and duration. When I scan these parameters from a file, everything goes to the first variable which is the name.
The file that I am scanning built this way:

```
name,path,duration\n
name,path,duration\n
name,path,duration\n
...
```

Function:

```
FrameNode* loadProgress(char* filePath)
{
    FrameNode* addFrame = NULL;
    FrameNode* frameList = NULL;
    char* frameName = 0;
    char* framePath = 0;
    int frameDuration = 0, lengthOfFile = 0;
    FILE* filePtr = fopen(filePath, "r");
    // read file
    if (filePtr == NULL)
    {
        printf("File wan't found in path: %s\n", filePath);
    }
    else
    {
        // get file length:
        fseek(filePtr, 0, SEEK_END);
        lengthOfFile = ftell(filePtr);
        rewind(filePtr);
        while (ftell(filePtr) < lengthOfFile)
        {
            // allocate memory:
            frameName = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_PATH_SIZE);
            framePath = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_PATH_SIZE);
            // read from file and insert in frame lsit
            fscanf(filePtr, "%s,%s,%d\n", frameName, framePath, &frameDuration);
            addFrame = createFrameNodeParameters(frameName, framePath, frameDuration);
            insertFrameNode(&frameList, addFrame, framesNumber(frameList));
        }
        fclose(filePtr);
    }
    return frameList;

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should always check the return value of your `fscanf` calls

Comment: Wow! Actually worked!! ```" %[^,],%[^,],%d"```Can you explain?

Comment: Oh ok, didn't know there is a thing like that... Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Note `"%[^,]"` fails to scan anything if no non-`,` is first seen.  Thus fails for `name,,duration\n`.